# How to fix Oracle hierarchical query returning duplicate records?

Tags: oracle, duplicates, hierarchical

While trying hierarchical query in Oracle using `connect by` it returns duplicate child records for each parent record (based on column association).

For example:

```
drop table t1 purge;

create table t1(en varchar2(10),bug number, mgr varchar2(10));

insert into t1 values('a',101,'z');
insert into t1 values('a',102,'z');
insert into t1 values('a',103,'z');
insert into t1 values('a',104,'z');
insert into t1 values('b',201,'a');
insert into t1 values('b',202,'a');
insert into t1 values('b',203,'a');
insert into t1 values('c',301,'z');
insert into t1 values('c',302,'z');
insert into t1 values('c',303,'z');
commit;

select en, bug, level from t1
start with mgr='z'
connect by prior en=mgr;
```

is returning following result:

```
EN  BUG LEVEL
a   101 1
b   201 2
b   203 2
b   202 2
a   102 1
b   201 2
b   203 2
b   202 2
a   103 1
b   201 2
b   203 2
b   202 2
a   104 1
b   201 2
b   203 2
b   202 2
c   301 1
c   302 1
c   303 1
```

But, what I was expecting was hierarchical display of each unique bug numbers based on the hierarchy defined in columns `en` and `mgr`.

The output I'm expecting is (based on the `mgr` column):

```
EN  BUG LEVEL
a   101 1
a   102 1
a   103 1
c   301 1
c   302 1
c   303 1
b   201 2
b   203 2
b   202 2
```

It would be a great help if anyone point out what am I missing here.

**Update**
Requirement to group by number of bugs by each employee. Expected output:

```
EN  BUG_COUNT   LEVEL
a   4           1
c   3           1
b   3           2
```

**Update 2**
If we have to group by the count at each employee and manager level, what would be the query? The expected output is:

```
MGR  EN   EN_BUG_COUNT  CUMULATIVE_BUG_COUNT    LEVEL
z    null         null                    10        0
z    a               4                     7        1
a    b               3                     3        2
z    c               3                     3        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create tree using distinct values of `en` and `mgr`. And only then join bug codes to it.

It can be done with the following query:

```sql
with dist_pairs as (
  select distinct en, mgr
  from t1
),
tree as(
  select en, level lvl
  from dist_pairs
  start with mgr='z'
  connect by prior en=mgr
)
select tree.lvl, t1.*
from t1
join tree on (t1.en=tree.en)
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d164/3).

---

Aggregated output is even easier:

```sql
select en, BUG_COUNT, level
from (
  select en, mgr, count(*) BUG_COUNT
  from t1
  group by en, mgr) dist_pairs
start with mgr='z'
connect by prior en=mgr
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d164/4).